# Qt's QFontMetrics::horizontalAdvance() missing for Code Editor Implementation

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2017, qt5.10

I'm implementing a code editor for a simple scripting language and have been using the Qt Code Editor Example (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-codeeditor-example.html) as a guide for implementing a QPlainTextEdit with line numbers. The example uses the base widget's fontMetrics() method 'horizontalAdvance' to query the width (or better the advance) of a single character.

The method `QFontMetrics::horizontalAdvance(QChar)` (see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#horizontalAdvance-1) can be found in the Qt documentation **but my implementation seems to be missing this method**.

I am using Qt 5.10.1 'msvc2017_64' on Windows 10 with Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.7.3. I have searched the headers for the missing method, but only found `QTextLine::horizontalAdvance()` which is not what I need.

I have replaced the `QFontMetrics::horizontalAdvance(QChar)` call with a call to `QFontMetrics::width(QChar)` which is working with my current font (Consolas) but I am not sure if its ok for every possible font.

Question 1) Has QFontMetrics::horizontalAdvance() been removed from current version of Qt, is my installation buggy or have I missed something?

Question 2) What is the correct way of getting the advance for a specific (non propotional) font?

Thank you for reading this and trying to help!

Comment: The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#horizontalAdvance-1) states that `QFontMetrics::horizontalAdvance(QChar)` wasn't available until Qt5.11.

Comment: Oh yes! I tought the code editor example has been around for a while and did not even check in this direction. Thanks a lot! I would accept your answer if you write one :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As [G.M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6371123/g-m) told me in a comment:

> The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#horizontalAdvance-1) states that QFontMetrics::horizontalAdvance(QChar) wasn't available until **Qt5.11**.

So switching to Qt 5.11 fixes this problem.

Answer (score 5):

You might use `width` instead of `horizontalAdvance`.

The member function `width` is listed in
[Obsolete Members for QFontMetrics](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics-obsolete.html#width) and it suggests to use `horizontalAdvance` instead of `width`.
I guess these two member functions have a similar behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this code to solve `error: no member named 'horizontalAdvance' in 'QFontMetrics'` and to make it work for all Qt versions:

```cpp
#if QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 11, 0)
  return qFontMetrics().horizontalAdvance(text);
#else
  return qFontMetrics().width(text);
#endif
```